# C++ queue with multiple values

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am looking for a queue with multiple values but the default `std::queue` supports only two values like

```
queue<int, int> myqueue;
```

I have eight elements and want the same functionality of queue (PUSH, POP, etc.) like this

```
queue<int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int> myqueue;
```

Comment: The `queue` template can't be parameterized over two arguments like you've shown.  Can you elaborate on what you mean by "two values" or "eight values?"

Comment: Try using a `queue<pair<int, int> >` instead.  If you have eight types, this will grow tedious; have a look at `std::tuple.`

Comment: You want to push and pop exactly eight ints at a time?

Comment: @Mat: yes, 8 elements at same time

Comment: I have to write PUSH and POP functionality myself :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply store `std::vector` in the queue for instance. Or if the values have different meaning, simply create a custom structure and store it in the queue instead. By the way `std::queue` stores a single value meaning each element is a single value(if that is what you meant).

Answer (score 3):

You're not using the queue correctly. By specifying `queue<int>`, you can use `push` and `pop` to insert as many elements as you want, see also: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue

If you want a container which can hold exactly 8 elements, you might want to use a boost::circular_buffer with a fixed size: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html

If you want to push 8 elements at once, just use a `std::vector` as the queue item, or a 8-tuple `tuple<int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int>` or a struct with an array member: `struct EightInt { int data [8]; }`.

Comment: I believe the OP meant each entry consists of 8 values

Comment: Oh, ok, he was changing the question after I posted my answer. Will update.

Comment: Thank you Anteru
Isn't there something which provides PUSH, POP as well like Queue otherwise I am thinking to go with struct. I am building a large queue in which I PUSH and POP messages one by one

Comment: Or an `std::array<int,8>`.